# Need RegExp help for Linux Bash grep command to filter out lines containing square brackets

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, square-bracket

Using the following example, I need to filter out the line containing 'ABC' only, while skipping the lines matching 'ABC' that contain square brackets:

```
2012-04-04 04:13:48,760~sample1~ABC[TLE 5332.233 2/13/2032 3320392]:CAST
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample2~ABC
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample3~XYZ[BAC.CAD.ABC.CLONE 232511]:TEST
```

Here is what I have, but so far I'm unable to successfully filter out the lines with square brackets:

`bash-3.00$ cat Metrics.log | grep -e '[^\[\]]' | grep -i 'ABC'`

Please help?

Comment: +1 for sample input, clear explanation of desired output AND some sample code! Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited based on comments:

Try `grep -i 'ABC' Metrics.log | grep -v "[[]" | grep -v "ABC\w"`

Input:

```
2012-04-04 04:13:48,760~sample1~ABC[TLE 5332.233 2/13/2032 3320392]:CAST
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample2~ABC
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample3~XYZ[BAC.CAD.ABC.CLONE 232511]:TEST
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample4~XYZ
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample5~ABCD
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample6~ABC:TEST
```

Output:

```
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample2~ABC
2012-04-04 04:13:48,761~sample6~ABC:TEST
```

Comment: If it works for you, would you mind marking the answer as correct?  Thanks!

Comment: note, no need to cat Metrics.log, simply supply that as the input to the 1st `grep. grep -i 'ABC' Metrics.log | grep -v "[[]"`

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answered. Noted about the cat. One more case: need to skip false matches, like ABCD, but not ABC:TEST.

Comment: Thanks. Last suggestion did not work for me in all cases, such as DABC, which I did not specify. I found this to work the best: `grep -i '\bABC\b'`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $cat log |  grep -v '\[.*\]' | grep ABC
```